# Can we force SQL Server for case sensitivity

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, ado.net

What if I want to authenticate user using `Stored Procedure` using `ADO.Net`? Is there any way to do this or directly authenticate or find other way?

Comment: That sounds dangerously like you're storing plain text passwords in the database. Don't do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use database collation for your idea.

you must use `SQL_Latic1_General_CP1_CS_AS` instead of you must use `SQL_Latic1_General_CP1_CI_AS`

Also you can apply your collation on the special columns.

For example :

```
CREATE TABLE yourtable 
(Name NvarChar(100) COLLATE SQL_Latic1_General_CP1_CI_AS, ...
```

Comment: perfect. As my table was already created, alter example would have been great. I dont wanted to be spoon feeded but would have been a perfect answer for other googlers. :) thanks